# Blueprint CSS Grid Layout Anomalies

Tags: css, html, blueprint

I'm adapting the Blueprint CSS framework for my web site project, but I'm noticing that the blueprint isn't following some of its own rules. I've run through the tutorials on their web site and tried Googling a solution, but nothing is working.

I'm trying to set up a page layout like so:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Image                     (header)             950px                |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Navbar |             Body (560px)                            | Ad Bar|
|       |                                                     |(190px)|
| 200px |                                                     |       |
|       |                                                     |       |
   ...                       .....                                ...
|       |                                                     |       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                          (footer)            950px                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like the Body to be flanked by a Navbar (with a right-border) and Ad Bar (with a left-border) that expand in height to match the height of the Body (scaling depending on how much content is in it), and a footer that is simply tacked on to the bottom. So far, the header and body appear perfectly. However, the Navbar doesn't span the height of the body. Also, the Ad Bar does not appear on the right of the Body, but rather wraps around to the extreme left (left of the Navbar and below the Body). The Footer doesn't seem to line up with the rest of the site either, as I wrote it to center-align text, but it's off-center (slightly to the left).

Here's my HTML5 code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="blueprint/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" /> 
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
        <![endif]-->

        <!--Import fancy-type plugin. -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="blueprint/plugins/fancy-type/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />     

        <title>My Web Site Home</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <!------------------------------------------------------->
            <div id="header" class="span-24" style="background: #F68712">
                <h1 id="siteheader"><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" id="header-image" /></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar" class="span-5">
                <div class="span-6">
                    <a href="#"><img src="home.png" alt="Home" /></a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="span-6">
                    <a href="#"><img src="newmember.png" alt="Member Sign Up" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="span-6">
                    <a href="#"><img src="memberlist.png" alt="Member List" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="main" class="span-12 prepend-1 append-1" style="background: #F5F5DC">
                <p>Some text.</p>

                <p>Some more text.</p>

                <p>Even more text!</p>
            </div>
            <div id="adbar" class="span-5 last">
                Ads.
            </div>
            <div id="footer" class="span-24" style="text-align: center">
                <h6 class="alt">Copyright &copy;2012 Joe Schmo.</h6>
            </div>
            <!------------------------------------------------------->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've followed all of the English tutorials on the site, but can't seem to figure out why it doesn't want to cooperate. I'm developing my site with Microsoft Webmatrix, and am previewing my site both in IE9 and Chrome. If anyone could lend a hand I'd *really* appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<hr style="clear:both; width:100%" />
```

try this just before footer div

Comment: No luck, it places the divider line but it's still longer than the container and the footer text is still off-center when the web page is maximized.

Answer (score 0):

For your sidebar you have a class of span-5 yet it contains 3 divs of span-6. If you remove the class attribute for the three menu divs as I assume that you want them to be the full width of the containing div, does this fix your issue?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Dave. The span-6 on the images was a typo I fixed after posting, but it didn't fix the issue I was having. Oddly, though, I tried copying and pasting the code I put above, fixed the typo, and now the ad bar looks correct in IE9, but doesn't appear at all in Chrome. Very odd.